# Problem to record video of screen with Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-recording

I don't know why but icon of record video of the screen of device is grey and it's don't work..

[image]

How can I get a video of the screen of the phone.

Comment: My first bet would be reboot - Android Studio can be a bit buggy with screenshots and ADB integration sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow these steps**

- Attach real device in developer mode
- If it is attached properly it will show green color logo , this means you are ready for recording
- Please update your android studio to latest version, if you still face the issue

Comment: thanks but it's steal grey , I use a Huawei p20 for debug. And I upgrade to las version